# Chainlink Automation upKeep not working. checkUpKeep is not calling performUpKeep

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, chainlink, chainlink-keepers

Our Dapp will have an NFT Auction functionality, which we are trying to automate 100% using chainlink. The auction winner will get the NFT and the Previous owner will get the highest Bid, Platform will get a small cut as well.
To do that, we are using CHainlink Keeper/Automation. I've set the `checkUpKeep` & `performUpKeep`, both are working fine when I'm doing everything manually. But when I am registering an upKeep for automaton.

When I input the deployed contract's address into the register upkeep box, it says `Unable to verify if this is an Automation compatible contract`. Why this warning?
How do I make the contract Automation compatible contract?
[image]

`checkUpKeep` is working good:
[image]

If I pass this `performData` into `performUpKeep` everything will work fine.

Code/Contracts: https://mumbai.polygonscan.com/address/0x7e2DA19C130cb3B483FA7f17C45c70716ABF5Fe8

Chainlink upKeep: https://automation.chain.link/mumbai/21891159634677518530356555981285976030474691922841692133624884405593696766700

Pls help, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`Unable to verify if this is an Automation compatible contract` usually stems from a contract that is not verified on the block explorer. The [contract you linked](https://mumbai.polygonscan.com/address/0x7e2DA19C130cb3B483FA7f17C45c70716ABF5Fe8) is verified and if you create an automation with it everything is good
[image: verified contract]

Your `checkUpKeep` function does return `true` when supplied with the input you show(`checkData`). However, you have the `checkData` set to `0x` in your automation.
[image: checkData]

With that input, it returns false.

[image: false return]

You will need to change the `checkData` to match your screenshot.

Comment: Hey thanks for replying. Actually I have found that (after lot of debugging) that the problem is with NFT gransfer Allowance. Can we use Chainlink upkeep for NFT Transfers? If yes then pla guide how.